# Best way of spawning and monitoring processes?

Tags: php, linux, logging, command, process

I'm going to be building an app that spawns three system processes (Linux). They will run for an estimates 2-8 minutes, and then finish their work and exit. Pretty standard.

I'm wondering the best way of:

- Spawning the processes
- Logging their output
- Performing an action when the process has finished its work

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the extension, use the PCNTL functions. They abstract you from getting the process ids, checking their status and so.

- `pcntl_exec` to start the process
- `pcntl_waitpid` with `WNOHANG` option to poll their current status
- To log the output, append `> /tmp/somefile 2>&1` to their command. use a different temporary filename for each process - you could generate it with `tempnam()`